# 1004: Application defined error when trying to examine cell contents

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through the rows in my sheet, adding cells B-F of the current row to a range to be copied to another sheet.  The cells in the row (B-F) should only be added to the range if the value in column G is "Active" and if the value in column C has a value (not empty/nothing/null/!#VALUE...)

I've tried several ways around it, but I keep getting 1004: App/Object defined error off  the first If statement

The msgbox shows me the range is valid, I've tried qualifying to the tiniest detail and also using Cells() instead of .range to no avail.

```
MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").range("G" & Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row).Value)

For i = Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To i = 1 Step -1
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Cells("G" & i).Value = "Active" Then
        If Not IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").range("C" & i)) Then
            Set selectRange = range("B" & i & ":F" & i)
            Set copyRange = Union2(copyRange, selectRange)
        Else
        'Do Nothing
        End If
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
Next
```

Am I just missing something simple here?  I've been banging my head over this for hours now.

...and for you eagle eyes out there, Union2 isn't a typo, just a user defined function to avoid not being able to join ranges set to "Nothing"

Comment: I think you cannot use a string with cells... cells("A1") returns that error, and your For syntax is, indeed, very strange...

Comment: Exactly. Use Range instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Change the second line to

   `For i = Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1`
2. Change the third line to

   `If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Range("G" & i).Value = "Active" Then`

Answer (score 0):

To start change:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Cells("G" & i).Value = "Active" Then
```

To

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Range("G" & i).Value = "Active" Then
```

Or

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Cells(i , 7).Value = "Active" Then
```

You also need to fully qualify all your ranges as alot of your ranges are pointing to the active sheet and NOT "staging" Unless it is the active sheet, but just to be sure you should use the following code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging")
MsgBox (.Range("G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row).Value)

For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Active" Then
        If Not IsError(.Range("C" & i)) Then
            Set SelectRange = .Range("B" & i & ":F" & i)
            Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, SelectRange)
        Else
        'Do Nothing
        End If
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
Next
End With
```

Also You are using `copyRange` in this scope without it being declared, I am assuming you are assigning it to a range earlier in your code but if not please make sure to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Cells("G" & i).Value
```

You can use these:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").Cells(i, 6)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").range(cells(i, 6), cells(i, 6)).value

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging").range("G" + strings.trim(str(i))).value
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the below Error:

[image]

Go to Home -> Select the cell for which you are getting Error-> Use clear all funtion to clear the method.

I executed the script again and it started working fine.

[image]